# How to keep the alfresco container modifications after an commit to new image?

Tags: image, docker, containers, alfresco

I created a container from the official alfresco docker-hub image, and then realized the development of my GED application.

What I want now is to commit these changes in an image so that I can later create containers containing those changes.

What i noticed, all the themes change and the modifications that I made to some files of the container are still not lost when i commit the image. but any development on the part of alfresco share is gone.

no idea please in how to keep the development or migrate it?

Comment: Can you add the `Dockerfile` you used to build your image to the question?  What data isn't appearing in the final image?

Comment: i did not use a docker file is just a docker run commande
the information are the sites,  the models, the users permession ...
`docker run --name="alfresco" -it -p 4001:8080 gui81/alfresco:201707`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've been running a pre-built image. What you would like to do now is to create a new image based on the pre-built image, but with your changes. To see how to do this, refer to https://github.com/Alfresco/acs-community-packaging. In docker-alfresco you'll see a Dockerfile. This file is used by Alfresco to build up the Alfresco Community Edition Docker image.

You don't need to do all that work because Alfresco has already done it for you. You can create your own Dockerfile and change the FROM to start from Alfresco's image, then add whatever you need to.

For example, I have an ACS enterprise image that I start with, then add my own AMPs. So the Dockerfile looks like:

```
FROM quay.io/alfresco/alfresco-content-repository:6.0.1.2

ARG TOMCAT_DIR=/usr/local/tomcat

RUN mkdir -p $TOMCAT_DIR/amps

COPY target/amps $TOMCAT_DIR/amps

RUN java -jar $TOMCAT_DIR/alfresco-mmt/alfresco-mmt*.jar install \
              $TOMCAT_DIR/amps $TOMCAT_DIR/webapps/alfresco -directory -nobackup -force
```

Yours would look similar, but if you aren't using Enterprise you'd change the FROM to be Alfresco's image.

You will likely also need to create your own Dockerfile that creates your own Share image. The pattern is the same. Start from an Alfresco image, then add your own WARs, like this:

```
FROM alfresco/alfresco-share:6.0.1.1

ARG TOMCAT_DIR=/usr/local/tomcat

RUN mkdir -p $TOMCAT_DIR/amps_share

COPY target/amps_share $TOMCAT_DIR/amps_share

RUN java -jar $TOMCAT_DIR/alfresco-mmt/alfresco-mmt*.jar install \
              $TOMCAT_DIR/amps_share $TOMCAT_DIR/webapps/share -directory -nobackup -force
```

Once you have your images building successfully you can use Docker Compose to build and start up your Alfresco repo image, your Share image, postgres, SOLR, etc.